# Если я начну перечислять(,) кого я недолюблюваю, то

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении.

Если я начну перечислять(,) кого я недолюблюваю, то я начну недолюбливать самого себя.

Answer (score 2):

> Если я начну перечислять(,) кого я недолюбл**и**ваю, то я начну
>   недолюбливать самого себя.

Запятая в скобках нужна: разделяет части сложного предложения.

Но я бы убрал второе и третье "я":

***Если я начну перечислять, кого недолюбливаю, то начну недолюбливать самого себя.***

Comment: Большое спасибо! :)

Answer (score 1):

Запятая ставится:
Если я начну перечислять, кого я недолюбливаю, то я начну недолюбливать самого себя.

Это сложное предложение с последовательным подчинением придаточных, старшей структурой является СПП с придаточным условным, двойной союз ЕСЛИ...ТО, а придаточное условное является главным для придаточного изъяснительного "кого я недолюбливаю".

Вопрос о  достаточно очевидной запятой **мог возникнуть в связи с правилом о постановке запятых на стыке союзов**, когда при наличии двойного союза ЕСЛИ...ТО запятая не ставится, но здесь не тот случай (стыка союзов нет).

Сравнить: Мне казалось, что если я сделаю ещё один шаг, то попаду в трясину.

Comment: Вера, здесь второе изъяснительное зависит от придаточного условного, в этом случае имеем не параллельное, а последовательное подчинение.

Comment: Да, правильно, при отсутствии местоимения ТО можно так перестроить предложение : Я начну недолюбливать самого себя, если я начну перечислять, кого я недолюбливаю.

Answer (score 0):

Обязательно нужна. Здесь "кого (я) недолюбливаю" - придаточное с местоимением "кого" в роли союзного слова. Такое придаточное подлежит обязательному обособлению.

Если убрать часть "я недоблюливаю", то "кого" скорее всего станет членом предложения (если по автор не имеет на этот счет своего особого мнения), в этом случая запятая не нужна.